# Bitcoin Core and Armory working together?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, synchronization, armory

I am confused, totally new to Bitcoin and not really a digital expert, so forgive me if the following is stupid.

I downloaded Armory two weeks ago and it asked me to also install Bitcoin QT which I did. I then created a wallet on Armory. I bought a small amount of BTC on bitcoin.de. As I wanted to transfer it to my Armory wallet, I clicked on "Receive Bitcoins". It showed a message asking me to not receive Bitcoins before I hadn't gotten online with Armory at least once. I continued anyway (Armory hadn't gotten online until then), Armory gave me a receiving adress which I used as payment adress for bitcoin.de. Now the BTCs "have left" my account on bitcoin.de. 
Right now, I have managed to get online with Armory hoping to see the BTC in my wallet but it is "empty". At the moment, Armory is building connection with the network and tells me it has to download the entire ledger which will take days.

I have two questions:

1. I already did the entire ledger synchronization with Bitcoin QT and it took several days. Do I have to do the entire waiting again with Armory just so that I can start using my Armory-generated wallet or is there a way around it?
2. Can I access my Armory-generated wallet only with the Armory client or is there a way to use Bitcoin QT to access it?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Your first question has already been answered [here](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13326/get-armory-to-use-an-existing-blockchain).

Comment: Alternately, to answer your second question, you could [export](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10978/can-i-use-the-official-wallet-to-recover-bitcoins-sent-to-an-alternative-wallet) the key you used to recieve coins from bitcoin.de, and [import it](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/how-do-i-import-a-private-key-into-bitcoin-qt) into Bitcoin-Qt. Anyway, since all of your questions appear to have been answered elsewhere, I'm going to vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is a little tricky to search for it the right way ;)

Comment: No prob! There's a trick to it: Type `site:bitcoin.stackexchange.com <your search query>` into google, because it's way better than the site search. Also, some of it is knowing all the ways that people phrase things. You'll pick it up if you stick around long enough. :)